# Проверьте и/или помогите решить 2 задачки

Tags: sql, инспекция-кода

Есть задача, я решил таким образом, прошу проанализировать и оценить составленные мной запросы.

Есть таблица К,  в нее записываются курсы валют (новая строка с датой появляется только в том случае, если произошло изменение курса).
Необходимо написать два запроса:
1.1 возвращающий курс каждой из валют таблицы на дату 07.01.2017
1.2 возвращающий максимальное значение курса каждой из валют которое было зафиксировано в декабре
[image: Таблица К]

Мое решение:
1.1

```
Select a.валюта, а.курс
from таблица К as a inner join таблица К as b
on a.дата = b.дата
where a.дата in (select max(дата)
                 from таблица К
                 where дата < '08.01.2017'
                 group by валюта)
```

1.2

```
Select валюта, max(курс)
from таблица К
where дата like '%.12.2016'
group by валюта
```

Если имеются ошибки (а это вполне вероятно), прошу истолковать их, спасибо.

Comment: посм. описание метки «инспекция кода» и внесите необходимые изменния в текст вопроса.

Comment: с 1 все отлично. Со вторым, я бы сделал что то вроде `дата >= '01.12.1016' and дата < '01.01.2017'` (только надо посмотреть формат даты по умолчанию в вашей СУБД). like он все таки для строк

Comment: В первом кажется есть ошибка. А именно в месте `where a.дата in (select max(дата)`.

Answer (score 0):

В обоих запросах не корректно сравнивается дата. Вы делаете сравнение даты со строкой, не могу сказать насчет всех СУБД, но в большинстве случаев база переведет дату в строку, а в таком случае '08.01.2017' будет меньше чем '18.01.1900', т.к. сравнение строк происходит посимвольно. Во всех СУБД есть специальные функции для преобразования строк в дату.

По первому запросу. Во from подключена таблица К as b, которая в данном случае абсолютно бесполезна, а в некоторых случаях может еще и данные задублировать. Касательно подзапроса тоже есть замечания, вы не учли ту ситуацию, что максимальная дата по одной из валют может совпасть с немаксимальной датой по второй валюте. В итоге ваш вариант запроса может как задублировать данные, так и вывести не корректные. Я бы предложил воспользоваться конструкцией EXISTS или видоизменить подзапрос.

```
SELECT a.валюта, а.курс
FROM таблица К as a
WHERE a.дата < '08.01.2017' AND
  NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT 1 
    FROM таблица К as b 
    WHERE b.валюта = a.валюта AND
      b.дата < '08.01.2017' AND
      b.дата > a.дата);

Select a.валюта, а.курс
from таблица К as a
where a.дата = (select max(b.дата)
             from таблица К as b
             where b.дата < '08.01.2017' AND
                  b.валюта = a.валюта);
```

По второму запросу все корректно.